# Apache camel to aggregate cascading REST service responses

Tags: apache-camel

I m new to Camel and wondering how I can implement below mentioned use case using Camel,

There are 2 REST web service offered by 2 different producer application. service1 will provide response containing order details & item ids associated with the order number. Service2 will provide item details for the given item IDs (in json data structure). The consumer application will make a call to Camel with order number. Camel has to make call to Service1, get order details plus the item IDs associated with Order. then, Camel has to extract the item ID's from first service response & pass Item IDs as parameter to Service2 to get Item details. Later merge the order details from Service1 & item details of Service2 (remove Item Id's & replace with Item Details) & respond to consumer application (as one JSON structure).

Appreciate if any appropriate solution suggestion to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You know what? The easiest way is to define a simple flow (i.e. a single route) to call service1, get the response from this service. Then, set the part of response you want to eventually send back in an exchange header. Set request to service2 in exchange body, invoke it and get its response. Finally, set the application response by response form service2 + getting service1 response from header.

Basically, make use of the fact that an 'exchange' runs through each of the route's nodes.

If you have any basic code that you've written to start on this, maybe I can help by suggesting anything to do with it.